# Converting HTML to Draft-JS ContentState in Python/Django

Tags: python, django, reactjs, draftjs

I'm migrating from using a html wysiwyg editor (CKEditor) to using Draft-JS and want to be able to convert existing HTML data into Draft-JS ContentState in a Django Migration but I've been unable to find a way to do this.

Is this possible? Or is this even the correct approach?

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same situation, and my goal is to just recursively parse the HTML document using BeautifulSoup, and use some helper functions to build the blocks as Python objects (you could replace this step with using a Python library for DraftJS). This way, you will have 100% control on the conversion and can control the DraftJS documents completely, with a thoughtful deliberation on custom block rendering and element mapping.

This is really not difficult if you just pull-up your sleeves. I used to fear such problems when there was no library available, but now absolutely don't mind the opportunity to not include another dependency for simple tasks like this.

**EDIT**:

Upon further thought, you should just consider doing this process in NodeJS with a DraftJS HTML->DraftJS library.

OR

I don't have the time to make a library out of this, but here is an initial version of the code to do this with `BeautifulSoup` that should get you started:

```py
import uuid

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import NavigableString


INLINE_TAGNAMES = ['b', 'strong', 'i', 'em', 'u']
INLINE_ENTITIES = ['a']
"""
Expects a body object (which is probably stored and used as JSON)
"""
def add_html_to_body(html, body=None):
    if body:
        body = body.copy()
    else:
        body = {'entityMap':{}, 'blocks': []}

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    _element_to_block([soup.body], body['blocks'], body['entityMap'])

    return body


def _element_to_block(parent_els, blocks, entity_map):
    has_blocks = len(blocks)
    if not has_blocks:
        blocks.append(_create_block('', 'unstyled', [], []))

    last_block = blocks[-1]
    parent_el = parent_els[-1]

    for el in parent_el.contents:
        if type(el) == NavigableString:
            # If this is part of an inline range, set it's length.
            reversed_parent_els = parent_els[:]
            reversed_parent_els.reverse()

            # Keep a track of the number of parent style and entity tags
            # we have already passed.
            inline_tagnames_counter = 0
            inline_entities_counter = 0

            for i in xrange(len(reversed_parent_els)):
                ancestor = reversed_parent_els[i]

                if ancestor.name in INLINE_TAGNAMES:
                    inline_tagnames_counter += 1
                    last_block['inlineStyleRanges'][-1 * inline_tagnames_counter]['length'] += len(el.string)
                elif ancestor.name in INLINE_ENTITIES:
                    inline_entities_counter += 1
                    last_block['entityRanges'][-1 * inline_entities_counter]['length'] += len(el.string)

            last_block['text'] += el.string

        elif el.name in ['b', 'strong']:
            last_block['inlineStyleRanges'].append({
                'offset': len(last_block['text']),
                'length': 0,
                'style': 'BOLD'
            })
            _element_to_block(parent_els[:] + [el], blocks, entity_map)

        elif el.name in ['i', 'em']:
            last_block['inlineStyleRanges'].append({
                'offset': len(last_block['text']),
                'length': 0,
                'style': 'ITALIC'
            })
            _element_to_block(parent_els[:] + [el], blocks, entity_map)

        elif el.name in ['div', 'p']:
            # If the parent didn't give blocks, we create an empty starting one.
            if has_blocks:
                blocks.append(_create_block(el.string or '', 'unstyled', [], []))

            _element_to_block([el], blocks, entity_map)

        elif el.name == 'a':
            # Create entity here.
            entity_key = str(uuid.uuid4())[:8]
            last_block['entityRanges'].append({
                'offset': len(last_block['text']),
                'length': len(el.string or ''),
                'key': entity_key
            })
            entity_map[entity_key] = {
                'type': 'LINK',
                'mutability': 'IMMUTABLE',
                'data': { 'url': el.get('href') }
            }
            _element_to_block(parent_els[:] + [el], blocks, entity_map)

        # More elses based on the kind of elements you expect to see like
        # u, ul, li, li, h1, h2, h3, table, etc. and entities with 'atomic' stuff.


def _create_block(text, type, inline_style_ranges, entity_ranges, data={}):
    return {
        'text': text,
        'type': type,
        'inlineStyleRanges': inline_style_ranges,
        'entityRanges': entity_ranges,
        'depth': 0,
        'data': data,
        'key': str(uuid.uuid4())[:8]
    }
```

Comment: Yep - I ultimately automated the task of exporting the html to NodeJS and then processing and saving it as json and importing it back.+